# SVG draw 1 degree arcs in circle using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I have created a SVG circle using Javascript and have to draw 1 degree center line arcs inside circle.

I am struggling with how to calculate the degree and loop through to create the filled arcs as per the image but 1 degree each and fill the circle

Here is what I have done so far

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var svgwidth=550, svgheight=550;
    var width = 500, height = 500;
    var x = width/2;
    var y = width/2;
    var r = width/2-10;
    svg.setAttribute("width", svgwidth);
    svg.setAttribute("height", svgheight);
    // create a circle
    const circle = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "circle",
    );
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  r);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 4px;' );
    svg.appendChild(circle);
    
    //Arcs
    var degree = 1;
    var totalArcs = 360;
    var middlePointX = width/2;
    var middlePointY = width/2;
    
    var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
    newLine.setAttribute('id','line2');
    newLine.setAttribute('x1', middlePointX);
    newLine.setAttribute('y1',middlePointY);
    newLine.setAttribute('x2',100);
    newLine.setAttribute('y2',100);
    newLine.setAttribute("stroke", "black")
    svg.append(newLine);
    
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srnx89h1/9/

Something similar to this but 1 degree fills

[image: sample]

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for calculations.

- Key is to set `pathLength=360` on a `<circle>`, and draw a **1/360** `stroke-dashoffset`
- draw every `<circle>` at `stroke-dashoffset=N` to draw N circle segements
- define it as a native **Web Component** `<svg-slices>` (JSWC supported in all modern browsers)
  and all you write is HTML:

```html
    <svg-slices></svg-slices>
    <svg-slices slices="100"></svg-slices>
    <svg-slices slices="360"></svg-slices>
```

[image]

```html
<style>
  svg-slices {
    width: 180px
  }
</style>

<svg-slices></svg-slices>
<svg-slices slices="100"></svg-slices>
<svg-slices slices="360"></svg-slices>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-slices", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.style.display = "inline-block";

      let colors = ["green", "gold","red", "blue", "magenta"];
      let length = this.getAttribute("slices") || colors.length;

      let slice = ( idx , color = colors.shift() ) => {
        colors.push(color); // cycle colors
        return `<circle stroke="${color}"      stroke-dashoffset="${idx}" 
                        pathLength="${length}" stroke-dasharray="1 ${length-1}" 
                 cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" fill="none" stroke-width="50%"/>`;
      };
      
      let slices = Array.from({length}, (el, idx) => slice(idx)).join("");
      
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0,0,9999,9999">${slices}</svg>`
    }
  });
</script>
```

- Note how, unlike Libraries, it doesn't matter when `<svg-slices>` is defined by JS code. Any existing *or future added* (but not yet processed) `<svg-slices>` will automagically be *Upgraded*.
- If you are drawing pie-charts, see: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/what-web-technologies-are-required-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-2021-spoiler-alert-a-standard-web-component-will-do-1j56